# Which failed, the wifi card or the wireless antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, laptop-repair, antenna

I have a hp 17 by1053dx laptop. My antenna became unsnapped from the wifi card, twice. After many failed attempts, I was finally able to snap them back together so they stay together but still have no wireless connections available. How can I know if the card or the antenna has failed?

Comment: What do you mean by “unsnapped”? Typically an RF antenna is either screwed in (with an appropriate RF connector) or there is a wire connected to the adapter and a receiver. It’s not clear how an antenna would be “unsnapped”

Comment: Thanks for that point. The antenna wire(s) has (have) little plugs that attach to the card.  I made that clear.

Comment: This is the message I got when checking the Realtech RTL8821CC 802.11ac PCLe adapter. This device cannot start. (Code 10). What is code 10? {Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful. I am going to try snapping them together again. Not sure why it is so difficult. Maybe some part of the connection got slightly bent or something.

Comment: Rambound, as John says, they are little plugs and they do fit together like a snap. That's why I used that word. They somehow became unplugged. This is the second wifi card I have had where the antenna came unplugged. This laptop only has one antenna

Comment: Two things, code 10 is IIRC a driver issue, and the antennas have a limited attach/detach cycle life, and need a lot more force than one expects to install them

Comment: Thank you Journeyman Geek.  I'm supposed to update the driver, but when I try they say this driver is the best and doesn't need or have an update. I will try harder to plug the two ends together after I take a magnifying glass to examine the two parts for anything that is impeding the operation.

Comment: I added to my answer that you might wish to take the laptop to a local shop and have them connect and test.

Comment: Yea, those connectors always make me worry the few times I've had to disconnect and reconnect them. They are basically small coaxial connectors, and so can handle some physical manipulation (tightening the outer sleeves, for instance, if its a loose connection), but because they have such a tight fit normally, I'd make sure that it actually IS a loose connection, and not simply a "not-yet-truly-connected" connection. You have two issues, as others have noted: The software error you're seeing is a driver/device error, and may not be an antenna error. Still, fixing both is a good thing.

Comment: Finally, adding additional info to the question itself is a good thing, making the question better. Right now people have to read down through the comments to get a full picture of the problem, which is not right or good.

Answer (score 1):

The card is a device whereas the antenna is a wire attached to the device.

Look in Device Manager at the wireless card.

**(1)** If the entry is normal and the tab says the device is working properly, reinstall the driver and test. If still not working, then likely the antenna and / or connection stub on the card  (that is, the antenna wire with a tiny plug has not properly been attached to the card). There also may be two antenna wires.

(This is how it appears on my laptops and matches your description of snapping in).

**(2)** If the entry in Device Manager has a red X (not working) then it well may be the card that is defective.

If you have an issue connecting the Antenna wire and are unsure, you might consider taking the laptop to a local shop, have them connect and test.

I can connect these pesky wires and on an older ThinkPad, I was able to ascertain the card needed replacing as the Antennae appeared good.